# Will all the mass collapse in one place?

Tags: mass, universe

Will the stars, planets and everything in the universe collapse due to the gravity? Or does the constant expansion of the universe break that idea ? What will happen with the energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could have been beautiful, and indeed it would have been the case if the Universe consisted of "normal" matter — i.e. baryons and dark matter – above a certain critical density threshold (which you can calculate to [$\sim10^{-29}$g/cm$^3$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Density_parameter)). Unfortunately, as it was realized in 1998, a mysterious "energy" labeled dark energy seems to permeate empty space, having a repulsive rather than attracting effect on the Universe. As dark energy is a property of vacuum itself, the larger the Universe grows, the more dark energy there will be. That means that 7.5 billion years ago, enough dark energy was present to "win" over the gravitational effect of matter, causing the Universe to not only expand further, but to [accelerate its expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerating_universe).

Unless this dark energy turns out to somehow change its properties in time, the sad fate of the Universe is to grow indefinitely, become colder, darker, and emptier. The energy of matter will remain, but the energy *density* will go towards zero, as it gets more and more diluted. The energy density of dark energy, on the other hand, is constant, so its total energy will increase.